# XML Parsing (Performance Problems)

Tags: sql-server, excel, xml, vba, ado

Before anything, let me state that I'm stuck with the current stack that I'm using and I'm currently not able to transition to something else. Rather than letting me know that I should be using other stuff, I can't... so let's skip that.

**My users are mostly the following:**

- Excel 16.0, 64 Bit.
- Windows 7, 10
- Ram: Min(4 GB) - Max(8 GB)
- CPU: i5 to i7 (I'm running i7-3770 @ 3.4GHz)

**Basics:**

- The Excel Application that I've developed for internal company use uses ADO to talk w/ SQLServer.
- Currently, the entire query system is built to work with only 1 Recordset being returned at a time (If the only solution is to get multiple Recordsets back and work with those, it will require a good size rewrite to the core of the system)

**The Non-Basics:**

- The system is currently able to import 500 MB files into SQLServer in a minute or two by chunking queries into 100k row chunks and that works pretty well.
- When getting data from SQLServer, I have two different styles:

  - Standard 2-D Recordset (extremely performant)
  - A Recordset that contains a single String value of XML (unparsed) with the following std format:

```
<root>
    <*page*>
        <row>
            <*column*></*column*>
        </row>
    </*page*>
</root>
```

Example output:

```
<root>
    <tab_awesome>
        <row>
            <col1>Value 1</col1>
            <col2>Value 2</col2>
        </row>
    </tab_awesome>
</root>
```

I then take this XML and currently load the String value from the Recordset using MSXML's "Load" method. After loading and doing some validation, I'll transform the XML into this standard Dictionary structure that exports to [N] tabs and whatnot.

```
{
    "page_count": 1,
    "page_names": ["tab_awesome"],
    "pages": {
        "tab_awesome": {
            "page_name": "tab_awesome",
            "row_count": 1,
            "column_count": 2,
            "column_names": ["col1", "col2"]
            "data": [["Value 1", "Value 2"]]
        }
    }
}
```

***The Problem:***

- We have a number of Sprocs that return their results using the String XML... and when parsed contain multiple tabs of +100k rows per tab. Some Sprocs will return +1,000,000 records with +20 fields (all tabs are included in the count).
- My current problem is a Sproc for Amortizing. It's returning a string that's roughly 208 MB in size.

  - Receiving the data over the network takes a few seconds
  - Parsing of the String to XML using MSXML takes *3m35s* and the bossman wants it to go faster.

My thoughts:

- Possible to use Sax?
- Can I transport an XML Document from SQLServer though ADO so I don't need to Load it from the string form?
- xmllite.dll? (I see Rubberduck uses this. Matt, how's the performance & by chance, have the bindings for VBA?)
- Last resort, I'll rewrite my application's underlying query engine to handle multiple ADO Recordsets to deal with multiple tabs of data. If I do this, how do I get a single Sproc to return multiple Recordsets?

*I'm stuck using API calls to windows and VBA.*

hmm... one thing that is possible is to return each Tab as another row in the Recordset (still string XML). For each row, create a new process of Excel, parse/load that tab's information, send the XML back to the main process, close those helper instances of Excel...

Comment: This is too long, too broad, and too rambling to work as a question here.  Read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I was luckily able to solve this. With the machine that I have, I was able to bring down the processing time to 18 seconds.

```
    Option Explicit

    Implements IVBSAXContentHandler

    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ' Defined Events
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Public Event NoRecordsReturned()
    Public Event returnedRecordset(ByRef records As Dictionary)
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ' Enumerations & Types
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Private Enum enumLevel
        eRoot = 0
        ePage = 1
        eRow = 2
        eColumn = 3
    End Enum

    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ' Class Variables
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Private saxReader As New SAXXMLReader60
    Private Container As Dictionary

    Private DEPTH As Long
    Private page_name As String
    Private page_idx As Long
    Private row_idx As Long
    Private column_idx As Long
    Private column_value As String

    Private page_data() As String
    Private page_data_len As Long
    Private lst_first_row_headers As Object
    Private lst_first_row_values As Object
    Private lst_page_names As Object

    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ' Class: Initialization & Termination
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Call Build_Main_Container

        Set lst_first_row_values = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        Set lst_first_row_headers = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        Set lst_page_names = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    End Sub
    ' ------------------
    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        Set lst_first_row_values = Nothing
        Set lst_first_row_headers = Nothing
        Set lst_page_names = Nothing
        Set Container = Nothing
    End Sub

    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ' Class Properties
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Public Property Let parse(ByRef strRecordset As String)
        Set saxReader.contentHandler = Me
        saxReader.parse strRecordset
    End Property

    Private Property Set IVBSAXContentHandler_documentLocator(ByVal RHS As MSXML2.IVBSAXLocator)
    End Property

    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ' Private Subroutines
    ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_endPrefixMapping(strPrefix As String)
    End Sub
    Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_ignorableWhitespace(strChars As String)
    End Sub
    Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_processingInstruction(strTarget As String, strData As String)
    End Sub
    Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_skippedEntity(strName As String)
    End Sub
    Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_startPrefixMapping(strPrefix As String, strURI As String)
    End Sub

    ' // Start of useful Subs & Funcs
    Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_startDocument()
        DEPTH = 0
        page_idx = 0
        row_idx = 0
        column_idx = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_endDocument()
        If Container("page_count") = 0 Then
            RaiseEvent NoRecordsReturned
        Else
            ' // Finished and sending data back to consumer
            RaiseEvent returnedRecordset(Container)
        End If
    End Sub

    ' //////////////////////////////////////////////
    Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_startElement(strNamespaceURI As String, strLocalName As String, strQName As String, ByVal oAttributes As MSXML2.IVBSAXAttributes)
        Select Case DEPTH
            'Case eRoot
            ' // Not in use
            Case ePage
                page_name = strLocalName
            'Case eRow
            ' // Not in use
            Case eColumn
                If Not oAttributes.Length = 0 Then
                    If IsNil(oAttributes) Then
                        Call IVBSAXContentHandler_characters(vbNullString)
                    End If
                End If
        End Select
        ' // This goes @ the bottom
        DEPTH = DEPTH + 1
    End Sub

    ' //////////////////////////////////////////////
    Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_endElement(strNamespaceURI As String, strLocalName As String, strQName As String)
        ' // This goes @ the top \\ '
        DEPTH = DEPTH - 1
        ' // ------------------- \\ '
        Select Case DEPTH
            'Case eRoot
            ' // Not in use
            Case ePage
                Call pageEnd(page_name, row_idx - 1)
                page_idx = page_idx + 1
                ' // Reset: New Page
                row_idx = 0
                page_name = Empty
            Case eRow
                Call rowEnd(row_idx, column_idx - 1)
                row_idx = row_idx + 1
                ' // Reset: New Row
                column_idx = 0
                column_value = Empty
            Case eColumn
                Call columnData(row_idx, column_idx, strLocalName, column_value)
                column_idx = column_idx + 1
        End Select
    End Sub
    ' //////////////////////////////////////////////
    Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_characters(strChars As String)
        column_value = strChars
    End Sub

    Private Sub pageEnd(ByRef name As String, ByRef last_row_idx As Long)
        lst_page_names.Add name
        Call ProcessPage(name, last_row_idx)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rowEnd(ByRef row_idx As Long, ByRef last_column_idx As Long)
        If row_idx = 0 Then
            Call CreatePageArray(last_column_idx)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub columnData(ByRef row_idx As Long, ByRef column_idx As Long, ByRef tag As String, ByRef value As String)
        If row_idx  0 Then
            Call ArrayAppend(row_idx, column_idx, value)
            Exit Sub
        Else
        ' // First row: need to add column values to ArrayList
            lst_first_row_headers.Add tag
            lst_first_row_values.Add value
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ArrayAppend(ByRef row_idx As Long, ByRef col_idx As Long, ByRef val As String)
        If row_idx
```